# Extract Values from Byte Buffer

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bytebuffer

I am trying to put the values from one byte buffer to another byte buffer. Suppose source Byte buffer has limit of 20KB and the values present in that are only till 8kb for eg: {1,2,3,4.... till 8kb and after that 0,0,0,0,0,...till 20kb}
Now i want to copy only the 8kb values to the destination byte buffer not the "0" values.

Below is the code is tried.

```
ByteBuffer src = ByteBuffer.allocate(20000);
ByteBuffer dst = ByteBuffer.allocate(32000);
//Adding values to src till 8kb

byte[] b = new byte[src.position()];
src.get(b, 0, b.length); // to get the values from src byte buffer to byte array
if(dst.remaining() > b.length){
    dst.put(b); // to put values got from src to dst
}
src.clear(); // to empty the src
```

In this i do not get the values in byte array which were there in src. i get {0,0,0,0,0....} in byte array.

Could anyone help me in this, how to just copy the values which are there in byte buffer to another without getting null values. i.e empty ones.

Comment: Can you try this with a buffer of only 10 bytes and see what is happening in the debugger? It would be much easier to diagnose.

Comment: If you fill your source buffer to 8kB then it's position should be at 8kB, while its limit should still be at 20kB. So just flip the source buffer, making its position 0 and its limit 8kB, then put the source buffer in the target buffer (e.g. `target.put(source.flip())`, note a `BufferOverflowException` may be thrown if `target` does not have enough space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fill `src` with 8kb worth of data, the position at 8kb into the 20000 sized buffer.

You then call `src.get(b, 0, b.length)` which dutifully copies 8kb worth of data (because b.length = 8kb) into the b array... **starting from the current position, which is 8kb in**. So, it copies bytes [8192,16384) into your byte array. Which are, of course, all zeroes.

So, how do you fix it?

This is precisely what the `flip()` method of buffers is for: to flip from 'write' mode to 'read' mode. After src has gained 8kb worth of data, flip your buffer (at which point, position() is 0, and limit() is now what position was, i.e. 8kb), then this will work great.

Then to get back to the beginning mode (ready to write up to 20000 worth into the buffer), clear it.

That's the flow for buffers:

- You start at position = 0, limit = 20000.
- You read some amount of data (8192 in this case) into the buffer. At some point, pos = 8192, limit = 20000.
- you flip: pos is now 0, limit = 8192, capacity = 20000.
- You read all 8192 into something else; pos is now 8192, limit is 8192, cap is 20000.
- you clear pos is now 0, capacity is 20000, as is limit.
- go back to the beginning again. You can do this forever.

so, write into buffer, flip, read from it, clear, write into it, flip, read from it, clear - forever.

EDIT: I erroneously thought flip() would also transit you from 'read mode' back to write mode. It doesn't really do that, clear is better, updated the answer to reflect this.